# Cross Domain webservies call in Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I need to call different domain webservices in asp.net (vb).

here

```
Url: http://Example.com/
Method: MethodName
```

and i want to call above url web services in asp.net vb file.

if any one have good suggestion, please help me..!!!

Comment: What is the problem? There is no cross-domain problem in the code running on your web server.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that if the server code doesnt let you. This is called CORS. Search for this term you will many things. If the server lets you call Alloweb cross domains you can call of couse but this is very big security problem so I dont think that any website permit this.

Comment: i have some json data. which need to transfer to another domain webservice. where other domain user that data.

Comment: OK first, you must write web service under that domain. This web service can be asmx(script service) or wcf or whatsoever. Then you can use it as add service reference then you can use it. After this implementation you will get an error. This error is, cross domain error. You can fix this using cors.  But using js is recomended using ajax call you can easily call this service.

Comment: but is it possible to done my job using HttpWebRequest in .net ?. please note that i have php webservice link.

Comment: Yeah of course but(!) İf other domain (I mean server domain, where the json data is) is yours, yes it is possible of course. because you can use cors. But the source where the json is locate is totally external it is not possible because nobody lets this. If you are manager in two domain you can write web service and call. If error occurs use cors nugets or methods other developoment environments.